# Two while loops to single array?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, while-loop

I'm trying to take parts number from two different tables and put them in the same array, then rearrange them.

Strangely it gives parts number twice, but when I run the same query in phpmyadmin it gives each part number once. I spend whole day but could not correct this.

```
//first query

$finalData = array(); $sql="SELECT
    jobc_parts_p.part_no,
    SUM(jobc_parts_p.issued_qty) AS sale_qty  FROM
    `jobc_parts_p`  WHERE DATE_FORMAT(jobc_parts_p.date_time,'%Y-%m-%d') BETWEEN '".$f."' AND '".$t."'

GROUP BY jobc_parts_p.part_no";


$result = $conn->query($sql);
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){   
 $finalData[$row['part_no']][] = $row;
}
```

//second query

```
  $sql2="SELECT
        jobc_consumble_p.part_no,
        SUM(jobc_consumble_p.issued_qty) AS csale_qty
    FROM
        `jobc_consumble_p`  
     WHERE DATE_FORMAT(jobc_consumble_p.date_time,'%Y-%m-%d') BETWEEN '".$f."' AND '".$t."'
    GROUP BY
    jobc_consumble_p.part_no";

$result = $conn->query($sql);
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){   
 $finalData[$row['part_no']][] = $row;
}
```

/// rearanging data......

```
$rearrangedFinalData = array();
foreach($finalData AS $first) {
    foreach($first AS $data) {
        $temp = array();
        $temp['part_no'] = $data['part_no'];
        $temp['sale_qty'] = isset($data['sale_qty']) ? $data['sale_qty'] : $data['csale_qty'];
        $rearrangedFinalData[] = $temp;
    }
}
```

//output result

```
foreach($rearrangedFinalData AS $row) {
         $sr++;


            echo "<tr><td>$sr</td>
            <td colspan='2' >",$row["part_no"],"</td>                       
            <td align='center'>",$row["sale_qty"],"</td>
            </tr>";      
     }
```

RESULT

```
1    10R46    2
2    10R46    2
3    10R91    1
4    10R91    1
5    10M95    3
6    10M95    3
```

What i want:

```
1    10R46    2
2    10R91    1
3    10M95    3
```

First query print_r($finalData);

```
Array ( 
[10R46    ] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [part_no] => 
10R46     [sale_qty] => 1 ) )
[10R91    ] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [part_no] => 
10R91     [sale_qty] => 3 ) ))
```

Comment: Can you show your `finalData` array by print_r

Comment: edited pls check above.

Answer (score 0):

Because, you are looping twice:

**Modify**

```
$rearrangedFinalData = array();
foreach($finalData AS $first) {
    foreach($first AS $data) { // <-- Remove this extra loop.
        $temp = array();
        $temp['part_no'] = $data['part_no'];
        $temp['sale_qty'] = isset($data['sale_qty']) ? $data['sale_qty'] : $data['csale_qty'];
        $rearrangedFinalData[] = $temp;
    }
}
```

To:

```
$rearrangedFinalData = array();
foreach($finalData AS $first) {
        $temp = array();
        $temp['part_no'] = $first['part_no'];
        $temp['sale_qty'] = isset($first['sale_qty']) ? $first['sale_qty'] : $data['csale_qty'];
        $rearrangedFinalData[] = $temp;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for time, I tried before but gives me error. Notice: Undefined index: part_no in

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem lies within the $finalData where you store same results twice. (ofcourse from different tables though).

the first query creates a result of

```
$finalData = array(
'10R46' => array(0 => array('part_no' => 10R46, 'sale_qty' => 2)),
'10R91' => array(0 => array('part_no' => 10R91, 'sale_qty' => 1)),
'10M95' => array(0 => array('part_no' => 10M95, 'sale_qty' => 2))
);
```

then you run the second query and ADD to the finaldata again with this `$finalData[$row['part_no']][] = $row;`

so the $finalData is now something like

```
$finalData = array(
'10R46' => array(0 => array('part_no' => 10R46, 'sale_qty' => 2), 1 => array('part_no' => 10R46, 'csale_qty' => 2)),
'10R91' => array(0 => array('part_no' => 10R91, 'sale_qty' => 1), 1 => array('part_no' => 10R91, 'csale_qty' => 1)),
'10M95' => array(0 => array('part_no' => 10M95, 'sale_qty' => 3), 1 => array('part_no' => 10M95, 'csale_qty' => 3))
);
```

That is the reason why you double loop it and also get double results.

So i would combine the queries.

```
$sql="SELECT
jobc_parts_p.part_no,
SUM(jobc_parts_p.issued_qty) AS sale_qty,
SUM(jobc_consumble_p.issued_qty) AS csale_qty ## this part was added
FROM `jobc_parts_p`
LEFT JOIN `jobc_consumable_p` ON (jobc_consumable_p.part_no = jobc_parts_p.part_no) ## this part was added
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(jobc_parts_p.date_time,'%Y-%m-%d') BETWEEN '".$f."' AND '".$t."'
GROUP BY jobc_parts_p.part_no";
```

and now your result should look something like this without the secondquery

```
$finalData = array(
'10R46' => array(0 => array('part_no' => 10R46, 'sale_qty' => 2, 'csale_qty' => 2)),
'10R91' => array(0 => array('part_no' => 10R91, 'sale_qty' => 1, 'csale_qty' => 1)),
'10M95' => array(0 => array('part_no' => 10M95, 'sale_qty' => 2, 'csale_qty' => 3))
);
```

also if you don't expect there would be two rows with same part_no you can change

```
$finalData[$row['part_no']][] = $row; -> $finalData[$row['part_no']] = $row;
```

So you don't need to double loop it.

Comment: I really appreciate your time and efforts but both tables have different part numbers. forexample, if abc part# is in first query then it will not be in second query.

Comment: if that is the case i don't understand some parts of your code at all.
$temp['sale_qty'] = isset($data['sale_qty']) ? $data['sale_qty'] : $data['csale_qty'];
what are you achieving with that part?
if your part numbers are different from each query how do you determine what part's csale_qty are you trying to input into the sale_qty.

Answer (score 0):

```
$new_array = array_values(array_unique($rearrangedFinalData));
```

Remove the duplicates and rearrange the keys (if needed) before you put your array in the `foreach`.

Then you can use the `$new_array` to generate your html